# Adding users to Windows Azure Active Directory through .Net application

Tags: windows, azure, active-directory

I have a requirement where I want to add users into the Windows Azure Active Directory programatically through my .Net MVC4 Application.

What approach should I follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use [`WAAD Graph API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974482.aspx) for that purpose. Do take a look at the sample code here: [`MVC Sample App for Windows Azure Active Directory Graph`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Write-Sample-App-for-79e55502) especially the code sample for [`UserController`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Write-Sample-App-for-79e55502/sourcecode?fileId=105818&pathId=1401426124).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I was able to add users auccessfully. I have a next question.
I need to retrieve ObjectId of an application I tried following ways 
1. Graph Explorer : Sign In-> Gives me server error
2.With URL in the browser: https://graph.windows.net/abcdef.onmicrosoft.com/applications?api-version=0.5
which says -> Authentication_MissingOrMalformedAccess Token missing or malformed.
2 I tried Get method using fiddler -> Gives me same error ->Authentication_MissingOrMalformedAccess Token missing or malformed.
Can someone help me for this?

Comment: You may want to post this as a separate question.